# Updating indices into a Python list after removal of elements

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list `x` of integers. I also have another two lists `z1` and `z2`, each with a separate set of indices into `x`, where no element in `z1` is equal to an element in `z2`. I want to remove all elements of `x` corresponding to the indices in `z1`, to leave a list `y`. Then, I want to update the indices in `z2` such that they correspond to the respective elements in `x` as they were before this removal.

As an example:

```
x = [3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14]
z1 = [0, 5, 7]
z2 = [1, 2, 6]

y = []
for i in x:
    if i not in z1:
        y.append(x[i])

# Now I need to update the values of z2 ...
```

This should yield:

```
>> y
[4, 6, 8, 9, 13]
>> z2
[0, 1, 4]
```

How can I do this elegantly?

Comment: Can you clarify a little more what you're looking for?  Also, what is ```for i not in z1:``` supposed to do? (Aside from throw a syntax error)

Comment: Are the values be unique always?

Comment: I've edited the question a little - the `for i not in z1`: was incorrect. z1 and z2 never have any values the same.

Comment: ***Why*** are you trying to do this? It sounds tortured. What is the bigger picture? You can probably avoid needing to do this - tell us more.

Comment: `import bisect; z2 = [z - bisect.bisect_left(z1, z) for z in z2]` / `[z - sum(i < z for i in z1) for z in z2]`

Comment: I have proposed the broader question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492446/keeping-track-of-indices-after-creating-a-sub-array-of-original-matrix

Answer (score 2):

1. Make `z1` a set. This will help improve the performance of step-2.

   ```
   >>> z1 = set(z1)
   ```
2. Get all the matching elements from `x` based on z1

   ```
   >>> y = [item for index, item in enumerate(x) if index not in z1]
   ```
3. Get the old values from `x` and form a set

   ```
   >>> old = {x[item] for item in z2}
   ```
4. Then get index of all the values from `y`, if the data is not in `old`, to get `z2`

   ```
   >>> z2 = [index for index, item in enumerate(y) if item in old]
   ```

That's it.

```
>>> y
[4, 6, 8, 9, 13]
>>> z2
[0, 1, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x = [3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 13, 14]
>>> z1 = [0, 5, 7]
>>> z2 = [1, 2, 6]
>>>
>>> z2_values = [x[i] for i in z2]
>>> y = [item for i, item in enumerate(x) if i not in z1]
>>> value_to_indexes = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(y)}
>>> z2 = [value_to_indexes[v] for v in z2_values]
>>> y
[4, 6, 8, 9, 13]
>>> z2
[0, 1, 4]
```